# How to resolve NullPointerException on webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Can somebody, please, help me to figure out what is wrong with my test? I'm getting that NullPointerException error in Eclipse all the time.

MyTestcase:

```
public class ExampleTest extends Basetest {

    private LoginPage loginPage;
    private DashboardPage homePage;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        loginPage =new LoginPage(driver);
        homePage = new DashboardPage (driver);  

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        loginPage.load();
        loginPage.login();
        homePage.getWelcomeMessage();
        String actualWelcome=homePage.getWelcomeMessage();
        assertEquals("Welcome Admin",actualWelcome);

        homePage.logout();

    }

}
```

BasPage:
public class BasePage {

```
public WebDriver driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;
public String pageUrl= "http:/hrm.seleniumminutes.com"; 

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {


    this.driver=driver;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

}

public void load () {

    driver.get(pageUrl);

}
```

}

LoginPage:

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);

    }

    public void login() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("admin");;
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("Password");;
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();;
    }

}
```

DashBoardPage:

```
public class DashboardPage extends BasePage {

    public DashboardPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getWelcomeMessage() {


    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
    By.id("welcome"))).getText();


    }

    public void logout() {


     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
     By.linkText("Logout"))).click();

    }

}
```

BaseTest:

```
public class Basetest {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected WebDriverWait wait;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @After
    public void basetearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
}}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: what's the actual error message you're seeing?  Is it always the same class/line number?  Which one?

Comment: Show your error log

Comment: Give us BasePage code and the stack trace you're getting with your exception

Comment: Ok, I got 2 errors, both are java.lang.NullPointerException: 
 
1. at pages.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:15)  which correspond to:    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

 at pages.LoginPage.<init>(LoginPage.java:9) which correspond to:   super (driver);
 at test.ExampleTest.setUp(ExampleTest.java:23) which correspond  to: loginPage =new LoginPage(driver);
  
 2 java.lang.NullPointerException
 
 at test.Basetest.baseearDown(Basetest.java:30) which correspond to:         driver.quit();

Comment: Your pageUrl is invalid - missing a forward slash.

Comment: driver declaration is missing in ExampleTest class. try to debug by printing the value of driver in each class as you are passing the same session from one class to another. by this you will get to know where exactly it is having the value as null..

Answer (score 1):

driver declaration is missing in ExampleTest and DashboardPage class. Since you have WebDriver as protected in the Basetest class

```
protected WebDriver driver;
```

Its scope is limited to Basetest Class.
Define the driver as  public WebDriver driver in ExampleTest and DashboardPage class.
below is the syntax

```
public WebDriver driver;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need split this in all cases:

> return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
>   By.id("welcome"))).getText();

as

```
//only waiting
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("welcome")));
// real value
return driver.find_element(By.id("welcome")).getText();
```